# How to convert OffsetDateTime to Date with time

Tags: date, kotlin, datetimeoffset

I have offsetdatetime field and I want to convert into date field. I used

```
val submissionDate:OffSetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneOffset.UTC)
val date = Date.from(submissionDate.toInstant())
```

this conversion returns date without time detail. does I have to manually set time into `date` field like hh:mm::ss or any other inbuilt function there.

Comment: If you do need a `Date`, for example for a legacy API that you don’t want to change just now, why not just `Date.from(Instant.now())` or even `new Date()`? If you don’t need a `Date` for a legacy API, avoid that class, it is outdated. Stay with the modern API, java.time, exclusively.

Answer (score 6):

That conversion shouldn't work - there is no `Date.from` method that takes an `OffsetDateTime` directly as far as I see in my IDE and in the docs.

However, passing in an `Instant` to [`Date.from`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#from-java.time.Instant-) works fine for me (as in it keeps time information), for example:

```
val submissionDate: OffsetDateTime = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneOffset.UTC)
val date = Date.from(submissionDate.toInstant())
println(date) // Tue Jul 31 08:26:31 CEST 2018
```

Comment: Thanks, yes, you are right. I am passing toInstant only. that is typo mistake. but I tried simple test now, it also works for me. let me check in my project. why is it not working?

Comment: I have this date '2018-07-30T18:30Z' in my project. is this creating issue?

Comment: Let me guess, @bNd, you’re in India or Sri Lanka? Then 2018-07-30T18:30Z equals 2018-07-31T00:00 in your local time, which is what `Date.toString` prints, so you will see a time of day of 00:00. This is correct and expected. The time is there, it’s just 00:00.

Answer (score 0):

Convert your submissionDate to Instant

```
val submissionDate = OffsetDateTime.ofInstant(Instant.now(), ZoneOffset.UTC)
val date = Date.from(submissionDate.toInstant())
println(date)//Tue Jul 31 12:05:36 IST 2018
```